# Inequality between the height of a triangle and the product of the associated bisected lengths on the base

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Suppose that $ABC$ is a triangle with base $AB$ and height $XC$ of length $h$, where $X$ is the point of intersection of the height and the base located between $A$ and $B$.

Is the following observation $$(\measuredangle A+ \measuredangle B) \gt \measuredangle C \implies h^2>AX \times XB$$ correct? If so, how to carry out its proof?

P.S.  I faced this problem while trying to solve an equality between the sign of the algebraic sum of the angles and the sign of the algebraic sum of squares on the side lengths of a triangle.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Hint: Draw a circle with diameter AB. Relate $AX \times XB$ via the power of a point. Compare that against the height $XC$.

Comment: @CalvinLin thanks, your hint helped me solve the problem.

Comment: Please write up an answer.

Comment: @CalvinLin sure, I will soon

Comment: Another way - you can write it as $2h^2 = CA^2 - AX^2 + CB^2 - XB^2 \gt AB^2 - AX^2 - XB^2 = 2 AX \cdot XB$

Comment: @MathLover thanks, the law of cosines had slipped my mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the circle with diameter $AB$, the power of $X$ equals $AX\times XB$. On the other hand, in the corresponding triangle formed by $A, B$ and the point $P$ determined by the power of $X$ lying on the circumference, the sum of the new angles associated with $A$ and $B$ equals $\pi/2$.

In the original triangle, if $\measuredangle A+\measuredangle B > \measuredangle C$ then $\measuredangle A+\measuredangle B > \pi/2$, so that the tip of the height will lie higher than $P$, which concludes the proof.